# How can I configure the TapTool so it does not hide other data points when clicked?

Tags: bokeh

At the moment when a data point is clicked, all other data points are shaded. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
fig = fig.circle(x, y)
```

Ideally, I would like to increase size of the selected circle instead. Is there an easy why to do so?

#### Update

Seems we cannot change size... according to [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html):

> Only the visual properties of selection_glyph and nonselection_glyph are considered when renderering. Changing
>   positions, sizes, etc. will have no effect.

However, we can simulate it using `line_width` property, it becomes more fun if I combine it with `line_dish`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.15`, you can  set `nonselection_glyph=None` when you call a glyph method, for example:

```
p.circle(x, y, radius=radii, fill_color="navy", 
         line_color=None, fill_alpha=0.6, 

         # this is the new part
         nonselection_glyph=None)
```

Comment: followed, appreciated.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for Bokeh 2,4,3. It gives an AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'nonselection_glyph' to Circle.

Comment: Correct, it's not the glyph object (capital-C) itself that has that attribute, it is the `GlyphRenderer` that coordinates the different drawing states. Please open a new question with a complete minimal reproducible example if you have continued issue

Answer (score 0):

Using bokeh 2.4.3, [bigreddot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919262/6309717) doesn't work for me, I got "unexpected attribute" when using `nonselection_glyph` directly in `circle`'s call.

The following snippet worked however :

```
renderer = p.circle(x, y, radius=radii, fill_color="navy", line_color=None, fill_alpha=0.6) 
renderer.nonselection_glyph = None
```